# Efficient way to search and build list from a list(of string type) based on certain criteria - C#

Tags: c#, linq

I built a `list<string>`  that contain elements, for ex. as

Prop.John, Prop.Steve, Prop.Matt, Oper.A, Oper.D, Oper.E

Ultimately I need to build a list of values based on a criteria for ex; all elements that start with Oper.

I tried it this way but to no avail (Original list is called OriginalList)

```
var newlist = new List<string>();
var searchname = "oper";
newlist = OrignialList.Where(s=>s.contains(searchname));
```

How should I approach the above situation?

Comment: What you have seems perfectly reasonable (other than you need a `ToList` to hydrate as a new list).  What _specifically_ are you concerned about?

Comment: Also `Contains` on a collection of strings is case-sensitive by default, so you may need to adjust for that (e.g. you are searching for `oper` but your strings contain `Oper`).

Comment: `Contains` should be `StartsWith` if you are looking for elements that start with `oper`, as your questions asks.

Comment: I added .Tolist() in the end and then it worked. thanks!

Comment: Side notes: searching for title of the post (or similar text) is good step to do (preferably before clicking final "submit" on the post) - https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23%20select%20items%20from%20string%20list%20based%20on%20criteria... "Efficient" is not synonym of "can compile" - it generally imply that there some *inefficiency* in correct code you already have any you are looking to improve it in particular way (speed, memory, IO,...).

Comment: Thanks @AlexeiLevenkov I did search it first. I guess I did not type the correct keywords to reach the same post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `ToList()` method, which will create List with the results:

```
var newlist = new List<string>();
var searchname = "oper";
newlist = OrignialList.Where(s=>s.Contains(searchname)).ToList();
```

You could even have it like this:

```
var searchname = "oper";
var newlist = OrignialList.Where(s=>s.Contains(searchname)).ToList();
```

**Edit:**
Answer to the comment - yes you can. `Where()` will return you collection of items that have the `"oper"` string. You can call `Select()` method to do some transformation, something like this:

```
var newlist = OrignialList.Where(s=>s.Contains(searchname)).Select(s=> s.Replace(searchname,"")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks @jjczopek. Can I also split the newllist by removing "oper." and only pick the remaining values?

Comment: @Cartman23: see the edit to see how you can remove the search term from result.

Comment: Thanks @jjczopek. It worked. I had to create a new searchname string as searchname2 = searchname+"."